# Php runs on server, but not command line: "libssl.so.10: no version information available"

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

php is running on my server, though I'm unable to get it to run command line. I'm running this file:

```
<?php
echo "done";
?>
```

using this command:

```
php test.php
```

When I do, I get this error:

```
php: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10: no version information available (required by php)
```

Any ideas why this might be? The server is live, so I'm hoping to understand what's going on here before making any changes that might break my setup. I need php to run command line, so I can get an email receiving script working. I'm on nginx, running php-fpm.

Thanks for any pointers -

Comment: Did you update your system?

Comment: What do you mean? Update what?

Comment: The whole system?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the library version number is lower on the shared object.

Maybe you have two different openssl libraries on your system. You may have linked with one but php is using the other.

Try:

```
$ find / -name libssl.so*
```

and have a look at the versions installed.
Also have a look at

```
$ ldd `which nginx` | grep ssl
```

to find the library used by nginx.

and check

```
$ ldd `which php` | grep libssl
```

to find out what library php is using.

What operating system are you on?

Can you try upgrading to the latest openssl package provided by your OS vendor and restart nginx so that it uses the updated library?

And quoting from [nginx.com/blog](http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-05-june-2014-openssl-security-advisory/)

> If you have compiled NGINX yourself, you may have statically linked the openssl libraries. The ldd test will reveal no dependencies on the operating system libssl.so library. nginx -V will give you the compile-time options which should reveal the options you used.

Comment: Okay, I see these:

/usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
/usr/lib64/libssl.so
/root/install/openssl-1.0.1g/libssl.so.1.0.0
/root/install/openssl-1.0.1g/libssl.so

The output of the second is:

libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007fe26b2de000)

What am I looking at here? Is libssl.so.10 what's being used by everything on the system? What can be safely deleted?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I done in my test system and its working fine.Looking at the above output it look like you are using so many version of openssl. Please try to figure which one you are using at the same time remove the one not in use and make sure it will not break the other functionality

```
        php test.php
        done

        ldd `which php`|grep -i libssl
        libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x0000003edcc00000)

        rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
        openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64
```